# DataList items out of container div

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I have this DataList:

```
<div style="width:400px">
<asp:DataList ID="DataListVhi" Width="7%" runat="server" 
DataSourceID="LinqVhi" 
ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
RepeatDirection="Horizontal" HorizontalAlign="Left"
<ItemTemplate >
    <dx:ASPxButton ID="btCodiVhi" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CODI_VHI")%>'
    EnableDefaultAppearance="false"
    AutoPostBack="false"                                        
    UseSubmitBehavior="false"
    Width="23px" 
    Height="15px"
    Font-Size="9px"
        ondatabinding="btCodiVhi_DataBinding">
        </dx:ASPxButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

[image]

How I can do this?, I try a lot of things but none have worked.
Any help will be grateful, thanks.

Comment: Why do you have the width of the DataList set to `7%`? Have you tried removing the width?

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
<div style="width: 350px; overflow: auto">
```

Comment: overflow is automatically use scroll bar when data overflow from assign width.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I can not put a scroll maybe as a last option would place a scroll, becouse the page have a lot of content and the principal reason is the client dont want a scroll. Regards.